# How to compare array with nested array and print the matching pairs, not list of values that match? (Code helps explain)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift5

I'm not really sure how to put it into words, but the code should help.

```
var People = [

      .init(name: "Sam", friends: ["James", "Tom", "Rick"]),
      .init(name: "Tom", friends: ["Callum", "Steve", "Sam"]),
      .init(name: "Adam", friends: ["Harry", "Diane", "William"]),
      .init(name: "William", friends: ["Rodger", "Adam", "Bill"]),
      .init(name: "Guy", friends: ["Zack", "Frank", "Cody"])
]
```

I want to generate an alert that prints

```
" Sam is in the same social circle as Tom " / " Tom is in the same social circle as Sam "
```

and

```
" Adam is in the same social circle as William " / " William is in the same social circle as Adam "
```

and

```
" Guy has no common social circles "
```

The way I have attempted this is to first create an array of names: [String], then do the same for friends, converting [[String]] to [String] using the following functions...

```
func loadNamesArray() -> [String] {
    return self.People.map { $0.name }
}

func loadFriendsArray() -> [String] {
    let arrayOfFriends = self.People.map { $0.friends }
    let friends = arrayOfFriends.flatMap { $0 }
    return friends
}
```

I then cross compared the two arrays to alert any common people using this function...

```
func loadCommonInteractingArray() -> [String] {
    let output = loadNamesArray().filter{ loadFriendsArray().contains($0) }

    return output
}
```

But this just returns ["Sam", "Tom", "Adam", "William"], and I'm not sure where to go from here to get the results I want i.e. identifying matching pairs as opposed to just a list of those that match.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let friends: [String]
}
```

---

```
var people: [Person] = [
      .init(name: "Sam", friends: ["James", "Tom", "Rick"]),
      .init(name: "Tom", friends: ["Callum", "Steve", "Sam"]),
      .init(name: "Adam", friends: ["Harry", "Diane", "William"]),
      .init(name: "William", friends: ["Rodger", "Adam", "Bill"])]

func loadCommonInteracting(in people: [Person]) -> [String] {
    var connections: [String] = []
    people.forEach { person in
        let friends = people.filter{ $0.friends.contains(person.name) }
        for friend in friends {
            connections.append("\(person.name) is in the same social circle as \(friend.name)")
        }
        
    }
    return connections
}
```

---

```
let connections = loadCommonInteracting(in: people)
for connection in connections {
    print(connection)
}
```

This will print

> Sam is in the same social circle as Tom
>
> Tom is in the same social circle as Sam
>
> Adam is in the same social circle as William
>
> William is in the same social circle as Adam

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are trying to find every person who is included in any other person's `friends` array.

```
for person in people {
    let others = people.filter {$0 != person}

    for other in others {
        if other.friends.contains(person.name) {
            print("\(person.name) is in the same social circle as \(other.name)")
        }
    }
}
```

`People` model class has to conform to `Equatable` to do the above.

Comment: If People does not conform to Equatable `people.filter { $0.name != person.name }`

Comment: @LeoDabus  Do you know how I would put this into a function and return values that can be put into these variables: State var AlertStatement: String, and State var AlertOn: Bool

Comment: @Jithin  Do you know how I would put this into a function and return values that can be put into these variables: State var AlertStatement: String, and State var AlertOn: Bool

Comment: just create an empty array of string and append the string to it instead of printing it

Comment: @LeoDabus where the print statement was I've put AlertStatement.append("\(drug.name) is in the same social circle as \(inter.name)") but the variable is still an empty string?